# Merging 3 files together, works fine when merging the same three files but when mergin 3 different files, it doesnt want to read the 3rd file

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

So title says it all, im trying to concatenate 3 wordlists together however for some reason it does not want to read the 3rd list,

first wordlist words:

nand

minus

second wordlist words:

nor

negative

third wordlist words:

xor

plus

```
void merge3(string MFile3)
{

string file1name, file2name,file3name, outfilename, word1, word2, word3;
cout << "Enter name of first file: ";
cin >> file1name;
cout << "Enter name of second file: ";
cin >> file2name;
cout << "Enter name of third file: ";
cin >> file3name;
cout << "Enter name of output file: ";
cin >> outfilename;


ofstream inFileFour(outfilename.c_str());

ifstream inFileOne(file1name.c_str());
while (inFileOne >> word1) {
    ifstream inFileTwo(file2name.c_str());
    

    while (inFileTwo >> word2) {

        ifstream inFileThree(file2name.c_str());
    
        while (inFileThree >> word3) {
            

            inFileFour << word1 << word2 << word3 << endl;

        }
        inFileThree.close();
    }

    inFileTwo.close();
    
}
inFileOne.close();
inFileFour.close();

}
```

the wordlist with the errors, the first 2 word lists show but not 3rd one
[image]

the wordlist with all possible combinations expect with file

[image: 1]

If anyone can let me know what is going on here that would be great, im open to suggestions.

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), consider a chat with the duck, and see [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/3422102). Being able to step through your code and diagnose the errors is every bit as important as being able to write and compile the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third file is never read, you are reading the second file again:

```
ifstream inFileThree(file2name.c_str());
```

Comment: WOOOOW, im so sorry for my noob mistake, thank you for taking the time to look at it!

Comment: No problems, happens to everyone.